SwiftUI: Updating State When Scrolling to a New Item in ScrollView
I’m building a SwiftUI view that displays a vertical list of items grouped by date. I want to update the state variable datetimeID whenever the user scrolls to a new item in the list. Here’s my current implementation:
struct ProductsListView: View {
  @State private var datetimeID: Date?
  
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      Color.blue
      
      let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
      let startDate = calendar.startOfDay(for: .now)
      let endDate = startDate.addingTimeInterval(60*60*24*70)
      let interval = 60.0 * 60.0
      
      let array = Array(stride(from: startDate, to: endDate, by: interval))
      let dates: [Date: [Date]] = Dictionary(
        grouping: array,
        by: { calendar.startOfDay(for: $0) }
      )
      
      VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 3) {
        Text("Products Gallery")
          .font(.largeTitle)
          .fontWeight(.heavy)
          .foregroundStyle(.white)
        
        Text("Log: \(datetimeID?.description ?? "nil")")
          .foregroundStyle(.white).bold().font(.headline)
        
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
          LazyVStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 2, pinnedViews: [.sectionHeaders]) {
            ForEach(dates.keys.sorted(), id: \.self) { date in
              Section(header: Text("\(date.description)").opacity(0.4)) {
                ForEach(dates[date]?.sorted() ?? [], id: \.self) { time in
                  let components = calendar.dateComponents([.hour], from: time)
                  let hour = components.hour!
                  Rectangle()
                    .fill(hour % 3 == 0 ? .orange : .yellow)
                    .frame(width: .infinity, height: 20)
                }
              }
            }
          }
          .scrollTargetLayout()
        }
        .foregroundStyle(Color.white)
        .scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)
        .scrollPosition(id: $datetimeID)
      }
      .padding()
    }
  }
}

The datetimeID is updating when the user scrolls to a new section, which is expected because .scrollTargetLayout() modifier is added to LazyVStack. But I want it update when the user scrolls to a new item (Rectangle in the code), so I’ve tried adding it to Rectangle() but didn't work.
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

How about adding an anchor parameter? e.g. .scrollPosition(id: $datetimeID, anchor: .top). You want datetimeID to change to the time corresponding to the rectangle at the top of the scroll view, right?

Try setting an .id on the underlying rectangles.

@BenzyNeez adding .id did not solve the problem

@Sweeper adding anchor worked for me. Thanks!

As suggested by Sweeper in the comment, adding anchor parameter solves the problem.
.scrollPosition(id: $datetimeID, anchor: .top)

Thanks Sweeper !
